# Align left side of table with \parindent

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx

I am using the tabularx environment to present formal arguments, and at the moment the left column is aligned with the left margin of the text and the right column is aligned with the right margin. For instance:

[image]

How can I get the left column to be aligned with the paragraph indent, but the right column to stay aligned with the right margin? I've tried using the `changepage` package and the `\adjustwidth` command but that doesn't seem to be helping, nor does adding `\hspace{\parindent}` in various places. I'm sure there's a really simple way to do it but I don't know how.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx} %tables
\usepackage{tabulary} %tables
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{upgreek} %greek letters
\usepackage{amssymb} %modal operators

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}rXr@{}}
        (1) & $\varnothing \vdash \pi \leftrightarrow val(\ulcorner \pi \urcorner, \ulcorner \bot \urcorner)$ & ($\pi$ def.)\\
        (2) & $\pi \vdash \pi$ & (Assumption)\\
        (3) & $\pi \vdash val(\ulcorner \pi \urcorner, \ulcorner \bot \urcorner)$ & (1,2, MP)\\
        (4) & $\pi \vdash \bot$ & (2,3, \textit{V-Detach})\\
        (5) & $\varnothing \vdash val(\ulcorner \pi \urcorner, \ulcorner \bot \urcorner)$ & (4, \textit{V-Schema})\\
        (6) & $\varnothing \vdash \pi$ & (1,5, MP)\\
        (7) & $\varnothing \vdash \bot$ & (5,6, \textit{V-Detach})\\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\lipsum[3-4]


\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "How can I get the left column to be aligned with the paragraph indent". E.g., do you wish the `tabularx` environment to have width `\textwidth-\parindent`? Please advise.

Comment: I would like the list of numbers in the table to be aligned with the paragraph indents in the ordinary text. So the numbers should be aligned with the word 'Nulla' in the image above. Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default value of `\parindent` in the `article` document class is `1.5em`. To achieve your formatting objective, it therefore suffices to change

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} rXr @{}}
```

to

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\hspace{1.5em}} rXr @{}}
```

Since the overall *usable* width of the `tabularx` environment is decreased by `1.5em`, LaTeX will automatically decrease the width of the `X` colum by that amount in order to assure that it will continue to fit inside the textblock.

---

*Addendum*: In case you don't happen to know the value of `\parindent`, you could execute, say,

```
\newlength\origparindent
\setlength{\origparindent}{\parindent}
```

sometime *before* starting the `table` environment and replace

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\hspace{1.5em}} rXr @{}}
```

with

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\hspace{\origparindent}} rXr @{}}
```

Comment: Uh! Why not `\hspace{\parindent}`?

Comment: @egreg - Because `\parindent` is set to `0pt` inside `table` and `figure` floats.

Comment: But the first thing to remove here *is* the `table` environment! The OP uses `h!` in the (vain) hope that the table would really end “here”. If the object is a float there is no need to respect the indentation.

Comment: Anyway, you don't need such esoteric `\the\parindent`: just do `\newlength{\normalparindent}\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\normalparindent}{\parindent}}` and use `\normalparindent` where `\parindent` may be set to a different value.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks for the pointer (reminder?!) that `\setlength{\origparindent}{\parindent}` works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to know the value of `\parindent`, because TeX knows it.

Also you don't want a `table` environment, because it's a floating object and you quite likely want the material *there*, not somewhere else.

You can use an `enumerate` environment, properly set up with the help of `enumitem`. Pushing something to the right margin is easy with `\hfill`, so long as the preceding material allows for the placement, more precisely it wouldn't overlap the label.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{upgreek} %greek letters
\usepackage{amssymb} %modal operators
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{sidecond}
 {\begin{enumerate}[
    label=(\arabic*),
    leftmargin=\dimexpr\parindent+\labelsep,
    labelwidth=0pt,
    align=left
]}
{\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2][1-5]

\begin{sidecond}
\item $\varnothing \vdash \pi \leftrightarrow 
       \mathit{val}(\ulcorner \pi \urcorner, \ulcorner \bot \urcorner)$\hfill ($\pi$ def.)

\item $\pi \vdash \pi$\hfill (Assumption)

\item $\pi \vdash \mathit{val}(\ulcorner \pi \urcorner, \ulcorner \bot \urcorner)$\hfill (1,2, MP)

\item $\pi \vdash \bot$\hfill (2,3, \textit{V-Detach})

\item $\varnothing \vdash \mathit{val}(\ulcorner \pi \urcorner, \ulcorner \bot \urcorner)$\hfill
      (4, \textit{V-Schema})

\item $\varnothing \vdash \pi$\hfill (1,5, MP)

\item $\varnothing \vdash \bot$\hfill (5,6, \textit{V-Detach})
\end{sidecond}

\lipsum[4][1-3]


\end{document}
```

[image]

A couple of final notes. I used `\mathit{val}`, because otherwise the letters are too spaced out (because they denote the product of three variables). I left `\varnothing` even if I abhor it for denoting the empty set.

Comment: +1. :-) Another advantage of using an `enumerate` environment (instead of a `tabularx` environment as in the OP's setup) is that a page break inside the list is entirely possible.